# YouTube Data API daily quota reduced to 0

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

For some reason, I started getting 403 errors on my app(in development), the errors message was

> Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project XXXXXXXX....

This is weird because I was using the API for the last month or so with the same project, and didn't do any changes.

After looking in the project settings I noticed that the daily quota was reduced to 0.

The only thing concerning the API that I did was to request a quota increase in order to keep developing(The default quota stalled the dev on the search functionality of my app), but I didn't get any answer concerning that request other than asking for info, no warnings, or anything really.

I'm pretty sure that my app complies with the Terms of service, so I don't think that is the reason.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: helpful that you asked this. it's 2023, i have an old project and saw my quota of zero and didnt know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use an old project, then it's not gonna work. You'll have to create a new project.

1. Create a new project.
2. Enable Youtube API for it. (Your quota will be reset to 10,000/day)
3. Get new API key for it.

Use the new credentials.

Answer (score 2):

I would check your email it sounds like your project was [disabled](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#d-accessing-youtube-api-services).  Have you been though the verification process?

> YouTube reserves the right to disable or curtail your access to, or use of, specific YouTube API Services if your API Project has been inactive for 90 consecutive days. For example, YouTube could revoke your API Credentials, or reduce (or eliminate) your API Project's quotas for specific YouTube API Services. If your API Client's quota is reduced or eliminated, you may reapply for quota or a quota extension, and YouTube will review that application based on YouTube’s determination of your expected use of the YouTube API Services.

I would check your email.  I have several emails about projects i no longer use which have had the quota reduced to 0 over the last few weeks.

**How to reset**

No matter what the clients you have now are not going to work you need to reset the project.

- Delete all client ids you have now.
- deactivate then reactivate all APIs you need
- Create new client ids keys

Comment: As I mentioned above, it is an active project, it is in active development right now and has been making API requests since I first activated the API.
And I am checking my email every day(including spam) looking for an update about the quota increase request, but I didn't get anything at all from google/youtube concerning the API.

Comment: As i mentioned having your quota reduced to 0  sounds like your project was disabled. Why its disabled i cant say. I would check your email and read the page i linked there are several reasons why you could be disabled.  Make sure you have applied for verification.   However i still think that you would have revived several emails before you where disable.

Comment: Well, I'm 100% sure I didn't receive any email. And you are correct, it seems like it was disabled. I just thought that I would get a reason or something by email,  and the only place to contact them for support is through stack overflow, so I guess im stuck...

Comment: Stack overflow is not google support we cant help you with that.  However this is the [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSd5HxReFtxATJLNfLwQiucfQwYL295Xemgc6nhFXo1vcitg3A/viewform) i got in my email try filling it out.    Either way you can just create a new project and use that since your still in development make sure you apply for verification right a way i would bet it has something to do with that.

Comment: Thanks, I check about the verification. But I still think this question is relevant.

Comment: I didnt say it wasn't relevant but i doubt you will get any official response from google here if thats what your looking for.  I would try and reset the apis on the project see if that gets it working again.

Comment: I have a similar issue. There is a notice on the API quota editing page that says to contact Google Cloud sales and request a quota raise. I did that and all they could do for a personal project, is give me a link to Google Cloud Partners list. I do not understand the business process behind this and how I can actually get a quota raise. Why is the process so weird and difficult? OP, did you solve this issue and how?

Comment: Its a free api you get what you pay for you will need to apply for a quota and wait.