# How to regenerate Firebase Remote Config API keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am getting this error from Firebase:

```
com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_remote_config.zze: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code": 400,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
      "reason": "badRequest"
    }
  ],
```

The auto-generated keys were deleted in the process to restore quota to other disable API in the same project, as recommended somewhere.

How do i regenerate the API Keys for Firebase Remote Config?
Disabling and enabling the Firebase Remote Confing API doesn't recreate them.

Comment: *The auto-generated keys were deleted in the process to restore quota to other disable API in the same project, as recommended somewhere.* - as recommended where, exactly?  What did you do?

Comment: The YouTube API was disable due to lack of usage. I follow this guide :https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397243/2700303 

The project is for my quality environment, and i need to reactive it again.

Comment: I don't know why Remote Config would have anything to do with YouTube APIs.  They seem completely unrelated to me.

Comment: Didn't think so too, but the script didn't recover the quota for YouTube API. So i delete all the keys as posted in the script hoping that would reset the project.

Comment: I am guessing that there is no way to recover from that, otherwise you already would told me. Should i recreate the all project?

Comment: I would contact Firebase support.  Tell them exactly everything you did that lead up to this.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: It think it will be must faster if i recreate the all project. It is a quality environment, just more work, no real arm done. I can report anyway if you think it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by removing and adding again the `SHA` certificate fingerprints at Firebase console, project settings page.

Then, i download the `google-services.json` file and replace at the root of the project. Web API Key was no longer available, so the `google-services.json` file needed to be updated.

*Update*

I use google Sign-in, so i needed to recreate the default web client id apply used by Firebase project, by doing the following:

1. Create a new `Create OAuth client ID` for web application type.
2. Go to Firebase console, Authentication Page, Sign-in methods tab.
3. Edit the Google sign method. Fill the client ID and secret as in the print screen bellow.

[image] 
 4. download new `google-services.json` file and replace at the root of the project

Here the guide to add [google sign-in method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) to use in case of any doubts